# How to use Animated values in Glamorous Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, glamorous

I’m using [Animated](https://github.com/animatedjs/animated) for web and I’m wondering is it possible to use Animated Values in a Glamorous component?

Like:

```
const AnimatedImageContainer = glamorous(Animated.div)(({ translateY }) => ({
  transform: `translateY(${translateY._value}px)`,
}));

<AnimatedImageContainer
  translateY={this.state.anim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-200, 100],
    outputRange: [200, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  })}
>
  <AnimatedImage src={image} />
</AnimatedImageContainer>
```

Or like:

```
<AnimatedImageContainer
  css={{
    transform: [
      {
        translateY: this.state.anim.interpolate({
          inputRange: [-200, 100],
          outputRange: [200, 0],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        }),
      },
    ],
  }}
>
  <AnimatedImage src={image} />
</AnimatedImageContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to React Native you can wrap your component in `createAnimatedComponent()`.

Something like this (https://codesandbox.io/s/93202y1qyo):

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import glamorous from "glamorous";
import Animated from "animated";

const View = glamorous.div({
    display: "flex"
});

const Button = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(
    glamorous.button({
        position: "absolute",
        fontSize: 16,
        border: "none",
        display: "inline-block",
        padding: "10px 20px",
        textAlign: "center",
        borderRadius: 4,
        color: "#fff",
        boxShadow: "0 4px 6px rgba(50,50,93,.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.08)",
        backgroundColor: "red"
    })
);

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        animation: new Animated.Value(0)
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const { animation } = this.state;

        Animated.timing(animation, { toValue: 1, duration: 3000 }).start();
    }

    render() {
        const { animation } = this.state;

        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    style={{
                        opacity: animation
                    }}
                >
                    Fade in...
                </Button>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```